Charts not getting rendered in dynamic html
Charts not getting rendered in dynamic html. The generated html looks complete and accurate also show the chart data retrieved from the endpoint, just see a blank box instead of rendered chart.
Parent code:
getDynamicForm(formName, userId, document)
    .then(formContent => {
      // Display the dynamically generated form content in the form container
        document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = formContent;    
    })

getDynamicForm() code:
// get dynamic form content based on the side/top navbar button clicked
getDynamicFormContent(navbarBtnClicked, token, userId, document)
    .then(formContent => {
        console.log("...getDynamicForm() - formContent = ", formContent);
        resolve(formContent); // Return formContent
    })

getDynamicFormContent() code:
let updatedformContent  = fetchAndUpdateCharts(document);
document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = updatedformContent;
formContent = updatedformContent;
return fromContent;
// Function to generate the consolidated script block for Chart.js initialization
function generateScriptContent(charts) {
    console.log("...in ");
    let scriptContent = `
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
`;
    let  docLoaded = false;
    if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
        console.log("...document is loading");
        docLoaded = false;
    } else {
        console.log("...document has loaded");
        docLoaded = true;
    }

    
    // Generate Chart.js initialization code for each chart
    charts.forEach(({ title, containerId, data }) => {
        const rowDataPacket = data[0]
        const labels = Object.keys(rowDataPacket); // Extract labels from data object
        const dataValues = Object.values(rowDataPacket); // Extract data values from data object
        console.log("...in generateScriptContent - rowDataPacket = ", rowDataPacket);
        console.log("...in generateScriptContent - labels = ", labels);
        console.log("...in generateScriptContent - dataValues = ", dataValues);
        scriptContent += `
            const ctx_${containerId} = document.getElementById('${containerId}').getContext('2d');
            new Chart(ctx_${containerId}, {
                type: 'pie', // Adjust chart type as needed
                data: {
                    labels: ${JSON.stringify(labels)},
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '${title}',
                        data: ${JSON.stringify(dataValues)},
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.7)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: '${title}'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            });
        `;
    });

    // Close the script block
    scriptContent += `
        });
        </script>
        `;
    return scriptContent;
}

async function fetchAndUpdateCharts(document) {
    const endpoint = 'zzz'; 
    const host = "http://localhost:4000/";
    const url = host + endpoint;
    let formContent = '';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        }

        const results = await response.json();
        console.log('Fetched results:', results);

        // Start building the formContent structure
        formContent += `
            <form id="respond_events-form">
                <h2>Events</h2>
        `;

        // Array of charts with their titles and container IDs
        const charts = [
            { title: 'abc1', containerId: 'abc1Chart', data: results[0] },
            { title: 'abc10', containerId: 'abc10Chart', data: results[1] },
            { title: 'abc2', containerId: 'abc2Chart', data: results[2] },
            { title: 'abc3', containerId: 'abc3Chart', data: results[3] },
            { title: 'abc4', containerId: 'abc4Chart', data: results[4] },
            { title: 'abc5', containerId: 'abc5Chart', data: results[5] },
            { title: 'abc6', containerId: 'abc6Chart', data: results[6] },
            { title: 'abc7', containerId: 'abc7Chart', data: results[7] },
            { title: 'abc8', containerId: 'abc8Chart', data: results[8] },
            { title: 'abc9', containerId: 'abc69Chart', data: results[9] }
        ];

        // Append each chart dynamically to #chart-container
        charts.forEach(({ title, containerId, data }) => {
            formContent += `<div class="chart-container">
                                <h4>${title}</h4>
                                <canvas id="${containerId}" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                             </div>`;
        });

        // Close the chart-container and form tags
        formContent += `
                </form>
            `;
        document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = formContent;
        // Generate the consolidated script content for Chart.js initialization
        const scriptContent = generateScriptContent(charts);

        // Append scriptContent after formContent is built
        formContent += scriptContent;

        return formContent;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error for further handling
    }
}

